# How do I return a single row based on the aggregate of more than one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sorry for the ambiguous title, not sure how to search, or ask this question.

Lets say we have TableA:

```
RowID        FkId        Rank        Date
ID1          A           1           2013-3-1
ID2          A           2           2013-3-2
ID3          A           2           2013-3-3
ID4          B           3           2013-3-4
ID5          A           1           2013-3-5
```

I need to create a view, that will return 1 row for each FkId. The row should be the max rank, and max date. So for FkId "A", the query would return the row for "ID3".

I was able to return a single row by using sub-queries; first I get the MAX(Rank), then join to another query that gets MAX(Date) group by FkId & Rank.

```
SELECT TableA.*
(Select FkId, MAX(Rank) AS Rank FROM TableA GROUP BY FkId) s1 
INNER JOIN (Select FkId, Rank, MAX(Date) AS Date FROM TableA GROUP BY FkId,Rank) s2 ON s1.FkId = s2.FkId AND s1.Rank = s2.Rank 
INNER JOIN TableA ON s2.FkId = TableA.FkId AND s2.Rank = TableA.Rank AND s2.Date = TableA.Date
```

Is there a more efficient query that would achieve the same results? Thanks for looking.

Edit: Added ID5 since the last answer. If I tried a normal MAX(rank),MAX(Date) GROUP BY FkId, then for "A", I would get A; 2; 2013-3-5. This result would not match up to a RowId.

Comment: What is the data type of rank?

Comment: The row with the max date from all the rows with max rank? Or the row with max rank from all the rows with the max date? (these two may differ!)

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals: numeric

Comment: sqlfiddle with some data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2dce/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (presuming sql-server >= 2005):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT TableA.*,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FkId Order By Rank Desc, Date DESC)
   FROM Table A
)
SELECT RowID,FkId, Rank,Date
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: +1. Window functions are awesome. You can also use `RANK()` in place of `ROW_NUMBER()` if there is a possibility of 2 or more rows have same `FkId`, `Rank` and `Date`.

Comment: @ypercube: If i want all max-rows i would use `DENSE_RANK`(however, `RANK`works also here since there are no gaps at the first position), but OP has said that he wants a "...return a single row".

Comment: Yes, but he didn't tell us there is a guarantee there is only one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: my view would be multiple rows, but only one row per FkId.

Comment: @csthopper My comment was about what should happen if there was another row with, say, `ID6, A, 2, '2013-03-03'`. Should the query return row `ID3`, `ID6`, both, or just one (anyone) of the two?

Comment: @ypercube: You're example would return 2 rows. My timestamp will have  miliseconds so I should have unique dates for every record.

Comment: @csthopper: If you use `ROW_NUMBER` you will get one record even if there were two records with the same FkId,Rank+Date.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think this is it, still testing, but so far this has returned exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question (clarified in the comments to this answer) asks for:

1. A single row for each FkId
2. The Max Date and Rank
3. The results to correspond to a row in the original data.

In the case that there are FkIds with rows such that the maximum date and maximum rank are in separate rows, you'll have to relax at least one of these requirements.

If you're willing to relax requirement (3), then you can use [`GROUP BY`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php):

```
SELECT FkId, MAX(Rank) AS Rank, Max(Date) AS Date
FROM TableA
GROUP BY FkId
```

Given the extra information in the comments. That you want the latest, of the highest ranked entries for each FkId, the following should work:

```
SELECT FkId, Rank, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM TableA A
WHERE Rank = (SELECT MAX(Rank) 
              FROM TableA sub 
              WHERE A.FkId = sub.FkId 
              GROUP BY sub.FkId)
GROUP BY FkId, Rank
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle to show it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2dce/2).

Comment: `MAX(Rank)` and `Max(Date)` may not be in the same row though!

Comment: But what if ID1 had a date of 2013-3-5? This query return A;2;2013-3-5, which doesn't match up to a RowId.

Comment: That's a fair criticism. I guess I would counter with "What do you expect to happen in that case?" Do you want both rows or neither? I've edited my answer to clarify it's limitations and the scope of the question.

Comment: My goal is to get my results down to a single RowId for a single FkId. My users can add as many child rows as they want. When they enter a row, they specify the "rank" of the item. On save, I timestamp the row. My report needs to get the highest ranking child row. If there are rows with the same rank, then I go by last row entered.

Comment: Okay, after a couple edits, I think I have something put together that does what you want.

Comment: @Wilduck: Yup, your query does return the correct rows. Tim's example has the added bonus of including the origin RowId (although using a feature not available on earlier sql). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rank() and inline query to achieve it.

```
select * from TableA
where RowID in (
      select rowID from (
           select FKID, RowID, 
                  rank() over (partition by FKID order by [Rank] desc, [Date] desc) as RankNumber
                  from TableA ) A
      where A.RankNumber=1 )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/879e8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also be sneaky and accomplish what ljh suggested [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/879e8/2):

```
select top 1 with ties *
from TableA
order by rank() over (
  partition by FKID
  order by [Rank] desc, [Date] desc
)
```